# ${n \brack k} = \sum_{m=0}^{k}2^{(k-m)^2}{n-k \brack k-m}{k \brack m}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, summation

$${n \brack k} = \sum_{m=0}^{k}2^{(k-m)^2}{n-k \brack k-m}{k \brack m}$$

I need hint to prove this. ${n \brack k}$ is the number of $k$ dimension subspaces of $n$ dimension space over field $F_2$. I am thinking about using induction and Pascal identities for the Gaussian binomial coefficients but cant figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out this is special case of q-Vandermonde identity. Proof can be found here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Vandermonde_identity